# Поиск хотя бы одного элемента из списка в строке

Tags: python

Допустим, есть список логинов

```
users = ["igor", "mera", "miracle", "serg", "gena", "nol", "vasya",]
```

И есть переменная `username = input("Ваш логин: ")`

Нужно, чтобы при вводе логина он проверялся по списке и если такого не оказывается, то вывести приветственное сообщение типа `"Вы у нас недавно, добро пожаловать!"`. Если он есть, то вывести другое сообщение.

Я никак не могу разобраться с этим :( Убил на это пару дней, пробовал метод `str.find` и индексами списка, ничего не добился.
Поможете додуматься до решения?

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь оператором [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) (также `not in`).

***Пример:***

```
if username not in users:
    print('вы у нас недавно, добро пожаловать!')
else:
    print('другое сообщение')
```